# QCheckBox function connecting

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, pyqt6, qcheckbox

у меня возникла проблема из-за не совершенного знания библеотеки pyqt:
Я хочу менять тему всех виджетов в приложении по нажатию на QCheckbox. У меня есть файл theme.py c кодом:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *

class themes():
    def light_theme(self):
        if self.btn_bw.isChecked() == True:
        global clr_btn_text, clr_btn_bg, clr_btn_hover, clr_btn_prsd, clr_icon, \
            clr_toggle, clr_page_bg, clr_widgets_bg, clr_widgets_border, clr_page_text

        #LEFT MENU BUTTONS
        clr_btn_text = '#2b2b2b'
        clr_btn_bg = '#c3c3c3'
        clr_btn_hover = '#ececec'
        clr_btn_prsd = '#cccccc'

        #ICON
        clr_icon = '#3e3e3e'

        #TOGGLE
        clr_toggle = '#b4b4b4'

        #PAGES
        clr_page_bg = '#9c9c9c'
        clr_widgets_bg = '#d8d8d8'
        clr_widgets_border = '#4c4c4c'
        clr_page_text = '#090909'
    else:
        clr_btn_text = '#c3ccdf'
        clr_btn_bg = '#44475a'
        clr_btn_hover = '#272832'
        clr_btn_prsd = '#2c313a'

        # ICON
        clr_icon = '#c3ccdf'

        # TOGGLE
        clr_toggle = '#323844'

        # PAGES
        clr_page_bg = '#22252c'
        clr_widgets_bg = '#282c34'
        clr_widgets_border = '#c3ccdf'
        clr_page_text = '#ffffff'
```

В другом файле у меня код со всем виджетами, в него я импортирую класс themes.
Я хочу к примеру по нажатию на Checkbox`self.btn_bw = QCheckBox(self.frame)`
изменить цвет frame

```
    self.frame_basic = QFrame(self.page_3)
    self.frame_basic.setObjectName(u"frame_basic")
    self.frame_basic.setMinimumSize(QSize(450, 330))
    self.frame_basic.setMaximumSize(QSize(450, 330))
    self.frame_basic.setStyleSheet(u"QFrame {\n"
                                "   background-color: clr_widgets_bg;\n"
                                "   color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                "   border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                "}")
```

через `self.btn_bw.connect(themes.light_theme(self))` с `clr_widgets_bg = '#282c34'` на `clr_widgets_bg = '#d8d8d8'` но мне выдаёт ошибку

```
self.btn_bw.connect(themes.light_theme(self))
TypeError: PySide6.QtCore.QObject.connect(): not enough arguments
```

скорее всего я всё слишком усложняю и осуществить мою задачу можно намного проще, поэтому прошу помочь с решением проблемы

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QCheckBox
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, SIGNAL, QObject

dark_theme = """
QWidget#MainWindow {
    background-color: #333333;
    }
QPushButton#ButtonPrintMessage{
    background-color: #555555;
    color: #aaaaaa
}
"""

default_theme = """
QWidget#MainWindow {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    }
"""


class Theme(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
    def dark(self):
        if self.parent.theme_check.isChecked():
            self.parent.setStyleSheet(dark_theme)
    def default(self):
        if not self.parent.theme_check.isChecked():
            self.parent.setStyleSheet(default_theme)



class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(QSize(180, 120))

        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")

        box = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(box)

        self.theme = Theme(self)

        self.theme_check = QCheckBox('Тёмная тема', self)
        
        self.button_print_message = QPushButton("Напечатать сообщение", objectName="ButtonPrintMessage")

        self.theme_check.stateChanged.connect(self.state_changed)
        self.button_print_message.clicked.connect(self.button_print_message_click_handler)

        box.addWidget(self.button_print_message)

    def button_print_message_click_handler(self):
        print('Hello, World!')

    def state_changed(self):
        if self.theme_check.isChecked():
            self.setStyleSheet(dark_theme)
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet(default_theme)
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QCheckBox
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, SIGNAL, QObject

dark_theme = """
QWidget#MainWindow {
    background-color: #333333;
    }
QPushButton#ButtonPrintMessage{
    background-color: #555555;
    color: #aaaaaa
}
"""

default_theme = """
QWidget#MainWindow {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    }
"""


class Theme(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
    def dark(self, value):
        if value == 2:
            self.parent.setStyleSheet(dark_theme)
    def default(self, value):
        if value == 0:
            self.parent.setStyleSheet(default_theme)



class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(QSize(180, 120))

        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")

        box = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(box)

        self.theme = Theme(self)

        self.theme_check = QCheckBox('Тёмная тема', self)

        #QObject.connect(self.theme_check, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.theme.dark)
        #self.theme_check.connect(self.theme_check, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.theme.dark)

        self.theme_check.connect(self.theme_check, SIGNAL("stateChanged(int)"), self.theme.dark)

        self.theme_check.connect(self.theme_check, SIGNAL('stateChanged(int)'), self.theme.default)

        #self.theme_check.connect(theme, SIGNAL ('checked()'), theme.dark)
        self.button_print_message = QPushButton("Напечатать сообщение", objectName="ButtonPrintMessage")

        #self.theme_check.stateChanged.connect(self.state_changed)
        self.button_print_message.clicked.connect(self.button_print_message_click_handler)

        box.addWidget(self.button_print_message)

        #self.button_print_message.connect(QPushButton)

        #button = QPushButton(self, text="Call func")
        #QObject.connect(button, SIGNAL ('clicked()'), self.foo)

        #button.connect()

    def button_print_message_click_handler(self):
        print('Hello, World!')

    def state_changed(self):
        if self.theme_check.isChecked():
            self.setStyleSheet(dark_theme)
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet(default_theme)
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```